# Convert a data frame to other to be able to graph with billboard

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to convert this data frame "dataInit" to this "dataFinal", I need this to be able to graph with billboard, it is an exercise to see if you can help me with any code. Note that in 2014 Havana did not report value but in the final frame it has 0

```
date <- c(2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,2014,2014)
place <- c('Paris','Habana','London','Paris','Habana','London','Paris','London')
acc <- c(100,99,100,98,70,80,100,80)
dataInit <- data.frame(date,place,acc)

date <- c(2012,2013,2014)
Paris <- c(100,98,100)
Habana <- c(99,70,0)
London <- c(100,98,80)
dataFinal <- data.frame(date,Paris,Habana,London)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot_wider` to transform data from long to wide and set `values_fill` to specify what missing values should be filled.

```
library(tidyr)

dataInit %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = place,
              values_from = acc,
              values_fill = list(acc = 0))

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#    date Paris Habana London
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  2012   100     99    100
# 2  2013    98     70     80
# 3  2014   100      0     80
```

---

Another solution without external package:

```
dataFinal <- reshape(dataInit, timevar = "place", idvar = "date", direction = "wide")
dataFinal[is.na(dataFinal)] <- 0
dataFinal
```